# Block onmousedown for child element

Tags: javascript, events, delegates, onmousedown

Sorry for my bad english. I have the following construction.

```
<div onmousedown="drag_drop(ev)" class="abc">
     <img src="test.jpg"></img>
     <div class="xyz"></div>
</div>
```

When I drag the picture, the "onmousedown" event is triggered. How can I prevent this? I need the "abc" block being moved when "test.jpg" is dragged.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the target of the event is right, for example:

```
drag_drop = function ( evt ) {
  if ( evt.target.classList.contains( 'abc' ) ) {
    //you have clicked the outer div
  }
}
```

Comment: Such structure blocks the transfer of the whole block when you click on the picture. It is possible to transfer it only behind the block. How should I make div move when img is in focus?